# Why does initializing an objects method with double& not work?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, reference

I am trying to assign -1.4 to a double in an object c4 of the Complex class using the setRealPart method. However it gives me an error.

Here is the relevant code:

Prototype:

```
void setRealPart(double &);
```

Definition:

```
void Complex::setRealPart(double &real)
{
real = this->rpart; 
}
```

Implementation:

```
c2.setRealPart(-1.4);`
```

Consturctor:

```
Complex::Complex(double realpart,double impart)
{
rpart = realpart;
ipart = impart;         
}
```

The error I receive is: `No known conversion for argument from double to double&`
2. `No matching function call setRealPart(double)`

Comment: You can't bind a temporary to a non-const reference. You're trying to assign `this->rpart` to `-1.4`, too, which makes no sense at all.

Comment: Why are you using `double&` and not `double`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass a non-const reference to a function, the function is expected to be able to modify the element passed in. The signature of `setRealPart` suggests that the caller should be able to modify whatever you pass in (which is, of course, wrong: setters are not supposed to modify their arguments).

> I am trying to assign -1.4 to a double in an object c4 of the Complex class

Your assignment goes the wrong way then, too: you should be assigning `this->rpart = real`, not the other way around.

Since this is a setter, the best approach would be removing the ampersand, and pass the `double` by value:

```
void Complex::setRealPart(double real)
{
    this->rpart = real; 
}
```

Finally, since you are not planning to modify the value of `real` passed in, consider declaring it `const`, like this:

```
void Complex::setRealPart(const double real)
{
    this->rpart = real; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot bind a non-const lvalue reference to an rvalue, which is what you are attempting to do here:

```
c2.setRealPart(-1.4);
```

You need to either take a `const` reference. Besides that, your assignment is the wrong way around. This would work:

```
void Complex::setRealPart(const double &real) { rpart = real; }
//                        ^^^^^
```

or take the `double` by value:

```
void Complex::setRealPart(double real) { rpart = real; }
```

Comment: Or just do `double real`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Agreed, that would be the better option.